# Map two or more entities to one table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i need a solution for the following problem: I have an object withe two or more mm-relation to another object (the relation depends on the context).

Example:
Object 1 `Beetle` with the properties  `name` and `leftLegs`, `rightLegs`, each with mm-relation to

Object 2 `Extremity` with the properties,  `color` (dark, medium, light), `hairyness` (strong, medium, light, none)

I can't use single table inheritance, since i do not need (and actually don't want to use a discrimator column: a dark, non haired extremity can be left and right and I do not want double rows just with a diff in the discriminator column).

I can't use `@MappedSuperclass` `Extremity` with subclasses `leftLeg`, `rightLeg` because i do not want two tables but only one for the extremity properties.

Mapping `leftLeg` and `rightLeg` both to an `extremity` table seems to me like the natural solution like

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Table (name="extremity")
 */
class LeftLeg extends Extremity
{
  ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Table (name="extremity")
 */
class RightLeg extends Extremity
{
  ...
}
```

results in

```sh
In SchemaException.php line 113:
                                                   
  The table with name 'db.extremity' already exists.
```

I believe, there is a solution. Maybe I have to change the modelling somewhere but I am stucked and maybe anyone out there has been facing the same problem and comes up with a nice solution. :)

Comment: why not only having "legs" as property in Beetle with an n:m relationship to Extremity and maintaining the property "left or right" as an attribute of the relationship? Beetle 1:n BeetleHasLegs [left|right] n:1 Extremity

Comment: Maybe update your question with the left/right leg mappings that generated the error?  Keep it simple.  There is no particular reason why you can't have two mappings to the same table.  Always thought beetles had six legs?  Seems like LBA's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: @cerad yes, most of the time, they have six legs (or less, if one gets lost), that's why I chose the beetle as example (mm relation).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
The properties `leftLeg` and `rightLeg` both with mm-relation to `Extremity`. But with separate join tables defined:

```php
/**  
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Extremity::class, inversedBy="beetlesWithLeftLegs")  
 * @JoinTable(name="beetle_leftleg")  
 */private $leftLegs;

/**  
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Extremity::class, inversedBy="beetlesWithRightLegs")  
 * @JoinTable(name="beetle_rightleg")  
 */private $rightLegs;
```